# Can the interest on a cash out refinance for a rental property be claimed as an expense?

Tags: united-states, interest, refinance, rental-property, expenses

I currently have my home all paid off.  I am thinking about purchasing another property as my primary home, and renting out my paid off current home.  My question is should I:

1. Get a regular loan for the additional property
2. Get a cash out refinance on my current home and then claim the interest on this new loan as an expense and use the proceeds from the re-fi to purchase the other home.

Basically can I claim the interest on the refi as an expense?

(This is for California)

Answer (score 4):

[Publication 936](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p936.pdf) addresses this.

You are welcome to borrow up to $100K from this house to do whatever you wish, and it would be deductible. As littleadv stated, with proper paper trail you can borrow to invest. But as I read pub 936 I'm not seeing where it counts as an investment to buy a new home to live in.

Unless under $100K, I recommend financing the new house in the usual way, a mortgage secured by that house.

Comment: Thanks @JoeTaxPayer.  However as I read publication 936 page 2 (Part I), it specifies the following (acquisition debt).  Thoughts?:

Mortgages you took out after October 13, 
1987, to buy, build, or improve your home 
(called home acquisition debt), but only if 
throughout 2012 these mortgages plus 
any grandfathered debt totaled $1 million 
or less ($500,000 or less if married filing 
separately)

Comment: Right, a loan on house 1 does not count as acquisition debt for home 2, as far as I know. If you do it, keep a paper trail to prove that how it went, and it's only if you are audited you need to show this, but I'd not be surprised if it's now allowed. Tax code doesn't always address each and every precise issue.

Answer (score 2):

What you **should** do is up to you. You can talk to a *licensed* financial adviser to get an advice.

But re the question in the subject line - **NO**, cash-out interest is not deductible on its own right, unless its a HELOC for less than $100K.

If you use the money for investment, you can deduct it as an investment expense (against the investment income) under certain conditions, and you should discuss with your tax adviser (EA or CPA licensed in California) the details of such transaction.

Comment: @littladv  Isn't this considered (acquisition debt).  Check out figure A in publication 936:

Were all of your home mortgages taken out after 
October 13, 1987, used to buy, build, or improve the 
main home secured by that main home mortgage or 
used to buy, build, or improve the second home 
secured by that second home mortgage, or both?

A:Your home mortgage interest is fully deductible.

Comment: @KingKongFrog I believe you will be going contrary to regulations (doesn't mean contrary to law necessarily, but you'll have to be able to prove your point in court). Generally, if the loan was not **directly** used to finance the acquisition of the property it is secured by - it is not considered as an acquisition loan by the IRS. You'll have to talk to a good tax adviser (EA/CPA, not an un-enrolled professional) or a tax attorney to check if a position like this has been discussed in a court that you're in the jurisdiction of, and what the decision was.

Comment: @KingKongFrog in your case the loan is **not** secured by the property which you bought with the proceeds of the loan, even though the property you bought is indeed your primary residence, hence your problem